# Alternate adding and subtracting a number java

Tags: java, for-loop, addition, subtraction

Here's my current code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int n, sum = 0;
System.out.println("Enter n:");
n = input.nextInt();
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0){
        sum-=input.nextInt();
    } else {
        sum+=input.nextInt();
    }
}
System.out.println("The total sum is:"+sum);
```

Can someone please help to alternately add and minus an integer?

For example, if I enter `n: = 5` and ask the user to enter `4, 14, 5, 6, 1` then it will compute like `4 + 14 - 5 + 6 - 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (i > 2 && i % 2 != 0){
        sum-=input.nextInt();
    } else {
        sum+=input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

The first two numbers contribute to the result with the "plus" sign, their sign does not alternate, hence the additional `i > 2` condition.

---

*Side note:* I would suggest renaming `sum` to `result` and changing the output text to something like `System.out.println("The result is:"+result);`. 
The reason is that it's not the *sum* being calculated, to the name `sum` is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
int result = 0;
for (int  i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    int num = input.nextInt();
    result += (i == 1 || i % 2 == 0) ? num : -num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = 0, n, i = 2;
result = input.nextInt(); // initialise result with first value
boolean add = true;
while(i <= n){
     int num = input.nextInt();
     if(add){
        result += num;
     }else{
        result -= num;
     }
     add = !add // flip the value of boolean flag
     i++;
}
```

OR:

```
int result = 0, n, i = 2;
result = input.nextInt(); // initialise result with first value
boolean add = true;
while(i <= n){
     int num = input.nextInt();
     if(!add){
        num *= -1;
     }
     result += num;
     add = !add // flip the value of boolean flag
     i++;
}
```

**Edit:** Rather than adding first two values,
initialise result with first value, and then alternate `add` flag. No need to bother about `i's` value

Comment: both variants will calculate `4 - 14 + 5 - 6 + 1` rather than `4 + 14 - 5 + 6 - 1`.